# How to answer a clients question on "How accurate your logistic regression model is?"

Tags: self-study, logistic

There are various methods to test the model accuracy, but when it comes to clients you may face people who don't know AIC, ks-statistic, c statistic, confusion matrix, etc. So, how one should answer a question like ""How accurate your logistic regression model is?"

Comment: I would start with sitting down with the client and find out what they want to do with that model. Then we can together pin down what the client means with accurate. Once we have that, the relevant statistic will become clear enough, and easy enough to explain to your client.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> I would start with sitting down with the client and find out what they
> want to do with that model. Then we can together pin down what the
> client means with accurate. Once we have that, the relevant statistic
> will become clear enough, and easy enough to explain to your client.

– Maarten Buis